# changing visibility of dynamically created elements in angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, hidden-field

I want to display 2 carousel elements on my page, top and bottom. the bottom carousels are created through a for loop and I only want one of them to be visible based on the current active slide of the top carousel

my html

```
<div>
<ngb-carousel class="outter" id="Main"   (slide)="onSlide($event)">
    <ng-template ngbSlide id="{{i}}" *ngFor='let M of main; index as i'>
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/{{M}}/900/500" >
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>

<div #secondary *ngFor='let s of second; index as j'>
    <ngb-carousel *ngIf="show" class="inner" id="Second{{j}}" >
        <ng-template ngbSlide  *ngFor='let image of s.image; index as k'>
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/{{image}}/900/500" >
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
</div>
```

the corresponding ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef,  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousels',
  templateUrl: './carousels.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousels.component.css']
})
export class CarouselsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('secondary', {static: true}) SecRef: ElementRef

  public activeSlide: number
  public show

  public main = [944, 1011, 984, 777]

  public second = [
    {image: [0, 1, 2], name: 'a'},
    {image: [10, 11, 12], name: 'b'},
    {image: [20, 21, 22], name: 'c'},
    {image: [30, 31, 32], name: 'd'},
  ]


  public onSlide(slideData) {
    this.activeSlide = slideData.current
    if (this.activeSlide == 1)
    {
      this.show = true
    }
    else
      this.show = false
    console.log(this.activeSlide)
  }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.SecRef.nativeElement)
  }

}
```

So there are a 4 carousels on the bottom and I only want one showing at a time, changing when the top carousel changes slides.

Answer (score 0):

so I guess one solution is using `document.getElementById("Second0").style.visibility = 'visible'` this works decently enough. it wasnt working before but for some reason it is now. seems like this would only work if you know what the id's of the elements that you want to change are.